# .net ExternalSigninAsync MissingMethodException System.Threading.tasks

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I am attempting to sign a user into my site through Google. The Google signin works correctly, but I am getting a MissingMethodException in the AccountController method on the line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

The error is:

```
Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.
```

I have tried using System.Threading.Tasks in the AccountController. I've also looked for other places I could be using System.Threading.Tasks and tried to put it in there.

**Question:** What is causing this error, and how can it be fixed?

Here is the whole method that contains that line:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
    var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
    }
}
```

**Update**
With the advice of several commenters I have been trying to find out what's going on with Fusion Log but am still having trouble finding it. To be specific, I did the following: I set the ForceLog and LogFailures to 1 in the FusionLog registry, and gave it a directory. Then I built the website at 11:59, then waited a few minutes before I attempted to log into Google, which I did at 12:03.

I got a ton of logs for the original build, some of which had failures in it. But the site did build, so those must not have been fatal failures, I think. But when I actually tried to log in I only got a few logs, all of which operations are successful. 
[image: Log Files sorted by Date]

[image]

I won't list the full fusion logs, but here's a list of assemblies that never succeeded in binding on the original build:

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime
- iisexpresstray.resources

Could either of these have led to this error?

**Update 2**
Looking at other logs, I think that WebpageInspector.Runtime did successfully bind eventually. The only thing theat never bout was iisexpresstray.resources, but according to a blog about Fusion Log, I read that: "Unless you are explicitly debugging the failure of a resource to load, you will likely want to ignore failures to find assemblies with the “.resources” extension with the culture set to something other than “neutral”. Those are expected failures when the ResourceManager is probing for satellite assemblies." So now I really don't know what the failure is.

**Update 3**
Other things that didn't work

- reinstalling all packages
- cleaning and rebuilding the solution

**Update 4**
Mike Barry informed me that .net40 can't do async operations, so if any of my references refer to the .net40 version of a file then it won't work. I think my EntityFramework refers to the .net 40 version of the file, because the folder it refers to is `[PROJECT PATH]\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll`. But I cannot get it to refer to `[PROJECT PATH]\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll` no matter what I do. All my references in my properties and .csproj file refer to .net4.5 but when I uninstall and reinstall EntityFramework it stubbornly goes back to the .net40 folder.

[image: Current Visual Studio and NuGet version]

**Update 5**

I used a try-catch to get all the information about the exception. Here is what I got:

```
Exception System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<FindAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.<ExternalSignInAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at LangSite_151209.Controllers.AccountController.<ExternalLoginCallback>d__3a.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Administrator\Source\Workspaces\Lang Site 4.12\DEV\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 342
 data = System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
 helplink = 
 hrresult = -2146233069
 innerexception = 
 message = Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.
 source = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
 stacktrace =    at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<FindAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.<ExternalSignInAsync>d__1d.MoveNext()
```

Soma Yarlaggadda asked to see my packages.config, so here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.15.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

**FINAL UPDATE:** Never did get this solved. 50 rep down the drain for the bounty. I ended up just making a new site from scratch and moving my content in there.

Comment: Is your site correctly deployed? In particular, is `EntityFramework.dll` (where this extension method is defined) of the same version as your development environment?

Comment: Good question; it appears it isn't! I'm using .net 4.5 and it appears I have the EntityFramework for .net 4.0; the file is \packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll . This could very well be the problem. Do you know how to change this?

Comment: [Entity Framework 6.1.3 supports this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.firstordefaultasync), so that particular version is not your problem. I have no further suggestions on what could be wrong, other than hooking up a debugger/turning on fusion logging and seeing what version of the assembly gets loaded at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your solution to possibly remove some libraries with different versions? Do you have some libraries loaded from GAC and some from other location (dynamically for example with different version in different parts of project)? This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx) might be interesting together with fusion logging.  You do not necessary have to have a problem with FirstOrDefaultAsync method, but with some of the parameters that could not be resolved. So your problem might not even be a part of the EntityFramework.dll

Comment: I would myself go with fusion log and search for any assembly being loaded more than once for different versions and look for error in there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about Fusion Logging. I did not know about that. I'm trying to find it on my computer now, but that is a different question.

Comment: Okay, I have Fusion working, but I am having a hard time finding the log with the error in it. I get a whole bunch of logs when I start the app, and all the ones I have seen are labeled 'successful'. But I am not seeing any logs from when I actually get the exception. Should I be?

Comment: I've updated with the results of my Fusion Logs above, but I'm still having a hard time finding the error. I am getting some failed bindings when I originally build, but the site succeeded in building anyway. When I actually get the error, however, I don't see errors. Could my original binding errors on building have led to this exception?

Comment: Did anybody got a fix for this? I am too facing the same issue. My EF referenced is 4.5.

Comment: Nope. If you can I recommend you do you do what I did, which is make a new site and move everything over.

Answer (score 1):

The entity framework 4.0 dll in the nuget package does not include the FirstOrDefaultAsync method as .NET 4.0 does not have native support for async and await. Only the 4.5 dll from the nuget package has the method call. Bottom line: Make sure ALL projects in your solution are built for .NET 4.5 and they all reference the nuget package's 4.5 dll folder.

If you had a previous project that was 4.0 and you upgraded it to 4.5, the nuget reference does not get modified to the 4.5 folder. If you have another project that is 4.0 and still references the 4.0 dll it's reference to the 4.0 dll can overwrite the 4.5 reference at build time. All sorts of bizarre things happen if all projects in a solution don't reference the same package version and target framework. Check all of them!

Comment: I think my problem is with the EntityFramework, as I think it's still referring to the 4.0 version. It's very hard to tell but the Object Browser tells me that the folder for EF is `[sitepath]\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll`. That 'net40' suggests that it's referring to the wrong one. However I cannot seem to get it to change, whatever I do.

Comment: My project's target framework is set to .net framework 4.5.1, and my csproj file says the same thing. The reference to EntityFramework in the .csproj file is to `packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll`. I have tried using the package manager to uninstall and reinstall EF, but I still end up with the same directory. How do I change NuGet's stubborn insistence on the .net 40 version?

Comment: What version of visual studio and the nuget extension?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3

Comment: NuGet Package Manager 2.8.60723.765

Comment: Attached a screenshot above.

Comment: I don't have an environment to reproduce the issue. If you just remove the reference and add a new reference, but manually browse to the 4.5 path does it work?

Comment: No. I have tried that. Even when I manually choose to refer to the one in the net45 folder, then I look at it again and it is referring to one in the net40 folder.

Comment: Based on the initial comment here, I solved this problem by simply deleting the [sitepath]\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\ folder and rebuilding. Didn't think it would work but I was desperate.